# updating jquery from v1.11.0 to v1.11.3 breaks code

Tags: jquery, css, dom

To display/hide a table with header I use jquery.

In jquery v1.11.0 this line of code works:

```
$('#subnet thead tr').css("display","true");
```

changes **style="display : none"** of **tr** to true and makes it visible.

I updated to jquery v1.11.3 and now this line doesn't change the style of element.

What could be reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because `true` is not a valid setting for CSS's `display` property. Use `block` instead - assuming you want to make the element visible:

```
$('#enable_local_subnet thead tr').css("display", "block");
```

However you should note that it's best to not apply inline `css()` to elements as it ties the JS and CSS code together. For this reason it's better to use `show()`:

```
$('#enable_local_subnet thead tr').show();
```

Or to add a CSS class:

```
$('#enable_local_subnet thead tr').addClass('show');
```

```css
.show { display: block; }
```